# Bootstrap Navigation Toggle Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am having trouble getting my navigation toggle to work on mobile. The toggle button appears, and when I click it, my "Social" dropdown menu appears to the left of the toggle button. It doesn't show my other navigation links either.

You can find my code on codepen: https://codepen.io/jeremycollins/pen/VWvWme

Here is the code. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7:

```css
body {
 background-color: #222222;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Overclock' arial;
 }
 
#bio {
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding-left: 30px;
 }
 
#jeremy {
 margin-left: 100px;
 font-weight: 900;
 }
 
.jumbotron {background-color: #222222;}
 
.profile {
 border-radius: 50%;
 float: right;
 }
 
.navbar-brand {font-weight: 900;
}
 
#tagline {font-weight: 700;}

.thumbnails {
  
}
span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
 
.outer-line {
 width: 20%;
 border-bottom: 3px solid white;
 margin-top: 16px;
 }
 
.spacer {margin-top: 100px;}
 
button {color: #fff;}
 
.btn {background-color: #222222;}
 
.btn:hover {color: grey;}
 
#footercopy {margin-top: 16px;}

.icon-bar {
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  height:50px;
}

.nav.navbar-left{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
}

.nav.navbar-right{
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100px;
  position:absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #222222;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jeremy Collins</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Social Links <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/jeremyscottcollins" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/jeremycollins92" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeremycollins92/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/jeremycollins" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.freecodecamp.com/en/jeremycollins" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <a name="home"></a>
            <h1>Hello, </h1>
            <h1 id="jeremy">I'm Jeremy!</h1>
            <p id="bio">Full Stack Developer, System Administrator, & Entrepreneur</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive profile" src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/20449608?v=3&u=3028ad3dd7f5185b62b69ba4ad957e5ae7cacacf&s=400" alt="Jeremy Collins">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <span class="outer-line"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0">
                    <h1>{ Portfolio }</h1>
                    <a name="portfolio"></a>
                </span>
                <span class="outer-line"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+1!"></img></p>
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+3!"></img></p>
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+5!"></img></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+2!"></img></p>
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+4!"></img></p>
                <p><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x150/000000/FFFFFF&text=Project+6!"></img></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <span class="outer-line"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0">
                    <h1>{ Contact }</h1>
                    <a name="contact"></a>
                </span>
                <span class="outer-line"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">I'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse btn-block"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Submit</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fluid-width">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="footercopy">&copy 2017 Jeremy Collins</h4>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right bootstrap  links in `<head>`
check if you have this link: 
which is the JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you add these to your manifest (application.js) file when installing the gem? ( //= require jquery  &  //= require bootstrap-sprockets )  If you add them & restart your server.

Comment: Yes, I have that in the header. I've added bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css from the 3.3.7 release.